# How to resize an image that is possitioned in a BoxDecoration flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am wondering if it is possible to resize an image that is inside of a `BoxDecoration` container and called by the `AssetImage()`.

My code is:

```
Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                    height: size.height * .75,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/img/washing.png'),
                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        )),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
```

and follows...

The image is too big. I would like it small and in the top right corner.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using the size property in AssetImage.

Comment: yes i did inside the BoxDecoration

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Its size depends on your container Size. If you reduce of your container size then The image size automatically reduced. But you must use `BoxFit.cover` as fit

Here is the code sample -

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Help'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(
                'asset/images/download.jpg',
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

If you want to developed it without Decorated image I can help you. Please share your sample UI, I will created for you